# Identity Server Site Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have implemented identity server using an asp.net core mvc site.
Everything is working great with one exception.
My business would like to add a welcome message to the login screen that changes depending on where the user is logging in from.
If for example a user comes from "https://dev.website.com" then the message "Welcome Developer" should be displayed on the login page. Coming from "https://test.website.com" would result in the message "Welcome Tester" being displayed.
The question is, how can I identify where the request originated from? I somehow need to identity that a user is logging in from "https://dev.XXX" or "https://text.XXX" but I can't figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The http request you receive contains two headers with the address you want. Try to check the "Origin" and/or "Referer" headers.

```
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

Comment: I was hoping for an alternative solution to this if possible. As far as I'm aware, those header values are set by the browser and you can't guarantee they will always be populated?

Comment: Why don´t you create your own new header and add it to the request. If its just a name on a message there is no problem. Just don´t trust it for granting access to anything as it can be faked. I would also question with business if this title can be added to the user profile, as it seems to be more elegant to connect this title with the person than with the system.

Comment: Oh, and, to avoid injection attacks, do not replicate the raw header (or parameter) on your screen. Do create a list (whitelist) of valid titles and only show them on the screen if its on the list.